# C# - File Manipulation Galaxy S3 SD Card

Tags: c#, file-io, sd-card

I am currently trying to write a small program to check my SD card on my Galaxy S3 for music then check my music folder on my computer and copy anything I don't have on my phone to it and vice versa. Currently I am struggling to figure out the path to the SD card. The path windows is displaying when I go there in my file system "Computer\SCH-I535\Card\Music"  returns false when attempting to check that files exist at that path. I was hoping some one might be able to help me by telling me how to properly find the path to the SD Card. I am currently attempting to use C# because I wanted a nice WPF UI for this application. Here is the code I am attempting to use to get the files currently and it is throwing the exception I put in.

```
 namespace FileSync
 {
     public class SyncTools
     {
         private readonly string path = @"Computer\SCH-I535\Card\Music\test.mp3";

         public bool pbExist()
         {
             bool exist = System.IO.File.Exists(path);

             if(exist == false) {
                 throw new Exception("File not found.");
             }

             return exist;
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Is it mounted with MTP or USB-storage? Maybe the "normal" IO-libs doesn't work properly with MTP storage?

Comment: It is mounted with MTP and my phone doesn't have a way to change it to USB-storage.

Comment: The Galaxy S3 should support USB-storage mode. Mine does at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution via "Microsoft Shell Controls and Automation COM API" (shell32.dll)

see here: http://dev.flauschig.ch/wordpress/?p=212

Comment: I have an Android mobile (smartphone), but I dont' know get full path using t **"Microsoft Shell Controls and Automation"** neither I cannot found full source code sample.