# Access file on my android phone from C#

Tags: c#, filesystems, galaxy

I connect my galaxy s4 to my computer in USB cable.
I can see drive "Galaxy S4" in "My computer"--> "Portable Devices".
My question is how can I access a file on the device from C# application?
(I can't find full path to file, for example to jpeg file in folder 'Galaxy S4\My Pictures\Picture.jpeg')

Comment: I think the path should look like: Computer\GT-i9505\Phone

Comment: Oh I see what the problem is, I will create a test application.

Comment: I didn't succeed access the folder by the path 'Computer\GT-i9505\Phone'

Comment: Maybe useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12053720/cannot-detect-sony-xperia-in-eclipse

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read/write to a Samsung android phone/tablet from a C# windows app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17555911/read-write-to-a-samsung-android-phone-tablet-from-a-c-sharp-windows-app)

Answer (score 0):

Perform the following steps (on your Galaxy S4):

1. Settings
2. Developer Options
3. Enable Developer Options
4. Enable USB-debugging

With Developer Options enabled it is possible to access all the files.

Path of a file will look like:

C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\........